# The like-button show my like-count, but it's not visible in the facebook api

Tags: ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api

If i go to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/ and enter https://www.ballantinesbarproject.fr/?name=epicerie and select box-count as layout.
the like-button shows a like count, as expected, since I liked the page. However, if I look in facebook api:

REST:
https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=https://ballantinesbarproject.fr/?name=epicerie&format=json

FQL:
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select%20url,%20like_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%22https://ballantinesbarproject.fr/?name=charlatan%22

(though one user claims, he can se counts in the fql-api)

It says there is 0 likes. How come?

Comment: Not clear what you want to achieve here... The number of likes of the Page, or the specific URL?

Comment: the number of likes, it dispalys zero, even though there are likes. You can confirm this if you go here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/, put https://ballentines.herokuapp.com/?name=charlatan
 as url and box_count as layout, one like!

Comment: I see 0 likes. Screenshot: http://imgur.com/XyVePwb

Comment: try with https:// in the beginning

Comment: Still 0 likes: http://imgur.com/R0FNXPP

Comment: that is weird, I had a like just a minute ago. I re-liked the page. Would you mind testing again(i still see the error with the fql, even though I liked the page)

Comment: Now it's showing 1 like.

Comment: okay, great, still zero likes according to faebook api: https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=https://ballentines.herokuapp.com/?name=epicerie&format=json

Comment: Have a look at my answer

Comment: I like what I see :) Just need to test it, Haven't used fql with javascript before. So i need to sort that out in order to validate it.

Comment: There as been a bunch of people with similar experience out there, I'll start a bounty, hopefully we could all get some answers.

Comment: The FQL I showed in my answer works, at least for all my own test cases. So what exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should use the following FQL:

```
select url, like_count from link_stat where url="https://ballentines.herokuapp.com/?name=charlatan"
```

Gives me

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "url": "https://ballentines.herokuapp.com/?name=charlatan", 
      "like_count": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

as result...

Comment: I still get like_count: 0

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select%20url,%20like_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%22https://ballentines.herokuapp.com/?name=charlatan%22

Comment: Are you sure there's still a like?

Comment: Well, and the FQL shows two... To be honest, I'm a little bit confused about what you are doing :-)

Comment: You have to add a User Access Token to make this work if you request it directly: `https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select%20url,%20like_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%22https://ballentines.herokuapp.com/?name=charlatan%22&access_token={user_access_token}`

Answer (score 3):

Following query is the proper FQL Query for retrieving like or comments count for a link

```
 select url, like_count from link_stat where url="https://ballentines.herokuapp.com/?name=charlatan"
```

I have debugged the above Query with Graph Explorer

Reference : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?fql=SELECT%20like_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url%20%3D%20%27https%3A%2F%2Fballentines.herokuapp.com%2F%3Fname%3Dcharlatan%27

If you check on above link, you would get proper like_count (now 3). Screenshot below
[image]

If you check above Screenshot the application selected is "Graph API Explorer" which is the default App while debugging with Graph API explorer.

If you are logged in with your proper Developer Account. the application Dropdown would also have your Application.

So after switching to your Application, click "Get App Token" and then submit the Query.
Now the like_count would come 0 for the same query. See Below Screenshot.

[image]

Now click on "Get Access Token", this would ask you to Allow the App if you not already done so. After "Allow App" proper User Access Token would be loaded in "Access token" box and now again Submit your Query. Now the "like_count" would be 3 as expected.

[image]

**So you would need proper User Access Token to retrieve proper information from "link_stat" FQL table and App access token wont work for it**

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Priyadarshan is correct about App Access Token and that you need a User Access Token (even if FB says the table is public, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/). Still, the FQL he uses is exactly the same as mine.

Answer (score 0):

The Open Graph debugger shows that the `og:type` meta-data is missing. That could be related to the problem. Can you add it?

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ballantinesbarproject.fr%2F%3Fname%3Depicerie